# Grid column size is not recalculated properly when restoring a maximized window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to implement a kind of single-line tab control in WPF which shows scroll buttons left and right of the area containing the tabs. The tabs are implemented inside a custom control. The scroll buttons shall be displayed only if the window is too small to display all tabs.
When the window is resized by dragging on its borders, everything works as expected.
But when the window is maximimized and then restored, then the right scroll button remains hidden.

The problem seems to appear only if the `Visibility` property of the right scroll button is data-bound to a dependency property of the custom control that is updated within the custom control's Measure pass.

My question is: am I using WPF correctly here, or is there something that needs to be done in a different way? (Please note: I need to use the data-binding and the custom control; therefore please avoid answers that suggest to take a completely different approach.)

Here is a small sample program which illustrates the problem:

When width is small:

[image: Small window]

When width is large:

[image: Large window]

These are the files of the sample program:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="GridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:gridTest="clr-namespace:GridTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="theGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btnScrollLeft" Content="&lt;" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="30"/>
        <gridTest:MyCustomControl x:Name="cust" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnScrollRight" Content="&gt;" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="30"
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=cust, Path=ShowButton}"/>
        <TextBox Text="The content goes here..." Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 Background="LightGreen" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRedraw" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Redraw" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnRedraw_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
namespace GridTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRedraw_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            theGrid.InvalidateMeasure();
        }
    }
}
```

MyCustomControl.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace GridTest
{
    public class MyCustomControl : Control
    {
        static MyCustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));
        }

        public Visibility ShowButton
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ShowButtonProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowButtonProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowButton.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowButtonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ShowButton", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MyCustomControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            if (constraint.Width > 800)
            {
                ShowButton = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                ShowButton = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            double width = Math.Min(2000.0, constraint.Width);
            double height = Math.Min(50.0, constraint.Height);

            return new Size(width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridTest">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
                    <Border Background="LightCyan">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">Custom Control</TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The problem can be reproduced as follows:

- Make sure that the window is small, such that the right scroll button is visible.
- Now maximize the window. => The right scroll button should become invisible.
- Now restore the window to its original size. => The right scroll button should become visible again. (The problem is: the right scroll button remains invisible.)

**EDIT**: Just for information: I could reproduce the problem with both VS2010+.NET4.0 and VS2013+.NET4.51.

Comment: What is the value of `constraint.Width` in your `MeasureOverride` method when the `Window` is restored? I'm guessing that it must be <= 800 pixels. And why have you chosen to 'hard code' that 800? What if the user is running on a wide screen?

Comment: `constraint.Width`is 479 when restoring the window. The constant "800" is just for testing; the sample program has no practical use except to demonstrate the problem I am facing.

Comment: I have you debugged to see whether MeasureOverride gets called when you restore the window size?

Comment: I understand. But as far as your test program goes, *that* is why your `Button` is not visible.

Comment: @Sheridan: since 479 < 800 when restoring the window, `ShowButton` is set to `Visible` and therefore the button should become visible. I confirmed with the debugger that this actually happens when the window is restored.

Comment: Oh yes of course, sorry, my mistake. Having worked with some custom `Panel`s before, I *seem* to remember that the value passed into the `MeasureOverride` is *not* the *actual* size... try moving that code to the `ArrangeOverride` method and see what happens.

Comment: @Sheridan: yes, it works when Setting `ShowButton` inside `ArrangeOverride`. Thanks!

Comment: @fmunkert, in order to have this question marked as answered, I'll add my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dispatch your `ShowButton` visibility change back into the dispatch queue for this to work(give the application the time it needs for the render and in sequence) rather than do it directly in the `MeasureOverride` method.

So say I change your `MeasureOverride` to

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint) {
  if (constraint.Width > 800) {
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      new Action(() => ShowButton = Visibility.Collapsed));
  } else {
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      new Action(() => ShowButton = Visibility.Visible));
  }

  double width = Math.Min(2000.0, constraint.Width);
  double height = Math.Min(50.0, constraint.Height);

  return new Size(width, height);
}
```

You can see it works fine.

With the original code you posted, you can see that even when you maximize your `Window`, the `Button` on the right will be hidden but not actually `Collapsed` like that your setting it to, that would be again due to the same reason of the control not getting it's new size.

Also after restoring and having the `Button` remain hidden, if you re-size the `Window` by dragging it's size, you can see the button become `Visible` again.

By dispatching the `Visibility` change, if you have a break-point in your `MeasureOverride` function, you can see it gets called twice(once for `Window` size change and second size change due to `Button` being Hidden/Shown) essentially when maximizing/restoring the Window and thereby produce the correct dimension calculations and your desired output.

Comment: Your suggestion works; thanks! But I would like to understand why it works. Did you come up with this solution by trial and error? Or does the WPF documentation contain an explanation why setting this particular dependency property requires the use of the dispatcher queue?

Comment: @fmunkert I came up with this because of the fact that the maximize operation also showed the custom control not stretching to fill all available width and showing the `Button` portion as if Visibility was set to Hidden when it was actually Collapsed. <- That sort of behavior I've seen with `MeasureOverride`'s before when the parent layout is not **re-calculating** the children Width correctly. In your case this was due to the Visibility toggle, so dispatching that seemed obvious enough from that point. I did not really look for any documentation links for it, I guess you can find some tho.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with some custom `Panel`s before, I seem to remember that the value passed into the `MeasureOverride` method is *not* the actual size used... try moving that code to the `ArrangeOverride` method instead and see what happens.

Comment: This answer also is correct; but since I can only accept a single answer, I am accepting the one of Viv, because this was chronologically the first answer.

Comment: That's not at all a problem, as long as this question gets marked as answered.